# Arduino Serial.println() keeps transmitting data even when conditions are imposed

Tags: arduino-uno

I am using Arduino UNO and a bluetooth module.  I have used an `if` condition so that `Serial.println()` happens only once but it keeps on printing.  Please help. Below is the code.

```
//Begin CODE
char str;
String fnal;
int i;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  fnal="";
  i=0;
}

void loop()
{
  i++;
  if(i<2)
  {
    Serial.print('#');
    Serial.print('1');
    delay(10);
  }
}
```

According to this code `#` and `1` should be printed only once but in serial monitor the printing continues infinitely.

Comment: It works as expected for me, and the code looks OK.  If it doesn't work for you, try printing out the value of `i` (`Serial.println(i);`) and see if you can work out what's going wrong.

Comment: In `setup` add a Serial.print, eg. `Serial.println ("Starting");` to see if the board is resetting for some reason.

Comment: Try changing the `i++;` with `i+=1;`

Comment: The idiom `i++;` alters the value of `i`. The two forms you posted are identical in function. If you do `a = i++;` then `a` is the value of `i` before adding 1 to it. However 1 is added to `i`, whether or not you store the result. Alternatively `a = ++i;` makes `a` have the value of `i` **after** adding 1 to `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely an overflow issue.

You declared `i` as `int` which ranges from -32768 to 32767.
I wrote this code as an experiment:

```
void loop() {
  unsigned long now = millis();
  i++;
  if(i==0){
    Serial.println(now);
  }
}
```

The result is `i` overflows every 264 ms, so `if(i<2)` will be `true` many times per second.

A simple solution is to put `i++;` inside the `if` instead, like this:

```
void loop()
{
  if(i<2)
  {
    i++;
    Serial.print('#');
    Serial.print('1');
    delay(10);
  }
}
```

`i` will stop incrementing when the value is 2.
No more overflow.

Answer (score 1):

If you had put a Serial.print inside `loop` you would have seen the problem. Debugging displays are very helpful. Like this:

```
void loop()
{
  i++;
  Serial.println (i);   // <---- debugging
  if(i<2)
  {
    Serial.print('#');
    Serial.print('1');
    delay(10);
  }
}
```

Since you are adding 1 to `i` each time around the loop, how long do you think it will go before `i` overflows? It will go up and up, get to 32767 and then become -32768, and then count back to 0. During that time it will be less than 2, and it will do the printing of "#1".

Comment: I'll try that out Nick...I think that might have been the actual problem..I'll use a boolean variable maybe..thanks man!